# Flutter Firebase - Not able to fetch data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data from "savedGoal" collection and somehow it is throwing error (NoSuchMethodError). However same script/syntax of code is working absolutely fine for another collection on same firebase project. Please let me know what could be wrong here. Here is the script that I am running in ininState()-

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("savedGoals")
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((result) async {
        if (result.data().isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            goalAmount = result.data()['goalAmountFixed'];
          });
        }
```

Here is the screenshot of error that I am receiving while using "savedGoal" collection -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBQ9m.png)

Here is the firebase document screenshot-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpCuV.png)

Comment: there are some possibility for this error. Please share your firebase screenshot for more reference because it might be possible that there is no data in your "savedGoals".

Comment: print value and also print result and see what output you got?

Comment: I have updated my question with Firebase Collection and Document details.

Comment: @AhmadRaza print value is null

Answer (score 0):

Check `main.dart` to ensure that you have initialized Firebase correctly. In case you have not initialized Firebase in your project then try initializing it by adding this in main:

```dart
main() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
}
```

If that's not the case then can you please send add the logs related to this issue. Also cross check the format of the code. Use results.isNotEmpty() instead of results().data.isNotEmpity().

Comment: It is already initialized. As I mentioned in the question, accessing details from Firestore is working fine for other collection. The issue is only with this particular collection, "savedGoals"

Answer (score 0):

Then probably because `.where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)` returning null because no matching documents are available.

Comment: It won't work. As I have mentioned in the question, same query syntax is working with another collection. This seems to be issue with this particular collection or firebase collection issue which I still haven't found solution to.
Please let me know if you have any expertise in that area and may help me there.

Comment: @Alok do check my updated Answer.

Comment: I have commented this filter (where clause) and still not able to fetch the data. So this case is also eliminated.